# How can I use fl_chart showingTooltipIndicators?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

```
 /// You can show some tooltipIndicators (a popup with an information)
  /// on top of each [LineChartBarData.spots] using [showingTooltipIndicators],
  /// just put line indicator number and spots indices you want to show it on top of them.
  final List<ShowingTooltipIndicators> showingTooltipIndicators;
```

I found this, but I can't understand what should I do.
I tried to show the actual number value, not just a dot's y value in tool tip.
it said that I can use showingTooptipIndicators on top of each spot,

```
lineBarsData: [
        LineChartBarData(
          spots: [
            FlSpot(1, (double.parse(number[21])-50)/25+1),
            FlSpot(5, (double.parse(number[13])-50)/25+1),
            FlSpot(9, (double.parse(number[5])-50)/25+1),
          ],
          isCurved: true,
          colors: gradientColors,
          barWidth: 4,
          isStrokeCapRound: true,
          dotData: FlDotData(
            show: false,
          ),
```

maybe somewhere in here, But how?

```
class ShowingTooltipIndicators with EquatableMixin {
  /// Determines in which line these tooltips should be shown.
  final int lineIndex;

  /// Determines the spots that each tooltip should be shown.
  final List<LineBarSpot> showingSpots;

  /// [LineChart] shows some tooltips over each [LineChartBarData],
  /// [lineIndex] determines the index of [LineChartBarData],
  /// and [showingSpots] determines in which spots this tooltip should be shown.
  ShowingTooltipIndicators(int lineIndex, List<LineBarSpot> showingSpots)
      : lineIndex = lineIndex,
        showingSpots = showingSpots;
```

I think I can show the actual number value with just changing lineIndex, but still don't know where to type them.

Thank you for reading, and I will wait for your advice :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just Add this like this,

```
BarChartGroupData(x: 1, barsSpace: 2,
   showingTooltipIndicators: [0],
    barRods: [
    BarChartRodData(
        y: 30,
        rodStackItems: [
          BarChartRodStackItem(15, 30, AppColor.barBlue),
          BarChartRodStackItem(0, 15, AppColor.pink),
        ],
        width: barWidth,
        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.zero)),
  ]),
```

And if you want to design that particular tooltip, use this inside TouchTooltipData,
(follow this format -> BarChart-> BarChartData-> barTouchData: BarTouchData->touchTooltipData->
BarTouchTooltipData-> getTooltipItem)

```
getTooltipItem: (
    BarChartGroupData group,
    int groupIndex,
    BarChartRodData rod,
    int rodIndex,
    
  ) {
    return BarTooltipItem(

      rod.y.round().toString(),
      TextStyle(
        color: Colors.black,
    
      fontSize: 8.0.sp,

      ),
    );
  },
```